# Access denied while writing file to "DiagnosticReports"

Tags: c, macos

Can anyone please explain to me why I cannot open file for writing (macOS) under `/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports` (no matter the reason).

I know that this directory is owned by root, but when I'm using the terminal with the command `touch foo`, the file does get created without any problems (and I'm running as the same non-root user).

And when I'm trying to use the `open` syscall in my C program, I get error 2 (which is access denied).

That's the code that causes the error.

```
fd = open(path, O_RDWR);
```

Would like to know if there's a different between me running this program and me using the terminal to write to a file (again, same user)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The system does not permit you to open a directory as if it were a regular file.

After `open` (and many other system or library routines) fails, you can use `perror` (declared in `<stdio.h>`) to print a message about the error (based on the information set in `errno`). In this case, `perror("open")` prints “open: Is a directory” (or something similar).

Comment: So, It turns out I didn't set the `O_CREATE` flag to actually create the file, `perror` pretty much explained it as `no such file or directory` Thanks!!

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood the question; you were attempting to open a file within the directory, not to open the directory itself. This answer is not the right one for that.